# PHP include contents of another directory

Tags: php

For example,

My website is `mywebsite.com`. Public_html is the main directory and inside `public_html` there is a folder `sub_dir` and a file `index.php`. `sub_dir` has the following files:

index.php , profile.php , contact.php

Now I want `public_html` directory to act like `sub_dir` directory. Like if I visit `public_html/index.php` it will show the contents of `public_html/sub_dir/index.php` without being redirected there. If I visit `public_html/profile.php` it will show the contents of `public_html/sub_dir/profile.php`.

How do I do this?

Comment: Include 'sub_dir/index.php'; **or** use mod_rewrite / .htaccess to create a forwarding rule under the hood

Comment: Point your apache root directory to subdir?

Comment: perhaps `include('../sub_dir/index.php')`? (if you are in public_html/index.php) .. WAIT. Where are you fetching content from? I assume you selected public_html as your root directory.

Comment: If I use PHP's include, will sub_dir's profile.php work as public_html's profile.php? And I need to achieve this using only PHP, use of .htaccess is not allowed.

Comment: changing root directories is not allowed. I have to achieve this using PHP programming only!

Comment: @paranoid: when you access to your "mywebsite.com", what file is loaded? public_html/index.php?

Comment: Then just do this: `include('sub_dir/index.php')` for the index, `include('sub_dir/profile.php')` for the profile and so on. Why are you including these anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit:

I have just seen your comment about doing it only via PHP, because you can't change `document_root` While I still think using `.htaccess` would be a better solution, you could certainly do this only using PHP, here's a quick mock-up:

```
// Grab the URL parts
$url = parse_url("http://stackoverflow.com/posts/20420420");

// Redirect the user to the same path in `sub_dir`
header('Location: '. $url['scheme'] .'://'. $url['host'] .'/'. 'sub_dir'. $url['path']);
```

This would redirect the user to `http://stackoverflow.com/sub_dir/posts/20420420`.

Other people have suggested using [`include()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php), you could combine this with my [`parse_url()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) example above to dynamically call `include()` to load the file from `sub_dir`.

---

I see a few ways of doing this...

You could use PHP's [`header()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) function, but this wouldn't really be ideal.

You could also use `.htaccess`, something like:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^sub_dir
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ sub_dir/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

If you placed this in `public_html` requests would be passed to `sub_dir`. So if you requested `example.com/test.php` you would actually be loading `example.com/sub_dir/test.php`.

What's your hosting setup like? Depending on your environment you can also change your webservers `document_root`...

Answer (score 0):

There are some ways to do this.

1. Use `include()`

In file public_html/index.php

```
<?php include_once 'sub_dir/index.php';?>
```

1. Use `file_get_content()`

In file public_html/index.php

```
<?php echo file_get_content('sub_dir/index.php');// Show as text?>
```